# RadioButton in Sony Ericsson XPeria Android 2.3.4

Tags: android

I cannot change the background of RadioButton in Sony Ericsson XPeria Android 2.3.4 by 
button.setBackgroundDrawable
Is there any people who have experience about this problems?
Please share with me. 
Thanks you very much.

Comment: The problem is described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6219335/radiobutton-not-drawing-background-correctly). However, the solution's @StephenAsherson is used xml to change background, I want to used code to change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution:
I must make my own RadioButton by extending the RadioButton class and draw it by myself.